# How can I print the value at each t=1000 in a way better than the following?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Consider:

```
dt=10**(-3)
for i in range(1,10**7+1):
    t=i*dt;
    kounter=e**(t*(dt**3))
    if t==1000 or t==2000 or t==3000 or t==4000 or t==5000 or t==6000:
        print(kounter)
```

Now the above code in itself might be written in an infinitely better way but that is just to show what I want to do in my actual code in which I want to print the value of a variable at each 1000 step till the end (note in above I did it only till 6000 but I want it till 10,000) which looks absurd if the end time is very large.

I am sure there is a prettier and more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: `t%1000 == 0` have a look at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "each 1000 step"? Looks more like each *millionth* step.

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you whether the `t` value is suitable? (Hint: what happens if you try dividing `t` by 1000, and looking at the *remainder*? Do you know a simple way in Python syntax to get the remainder from a division?)

Comment: As an aside: I don't understand the purpose here. If you only want to `print(kounter)` on every 1000th iteration, then why not only *calculate* it on every 1000th iteration? Why not only *perform* every 1000th iteration? (hint: can you think of a way, using the full power of the `range` function, to make `i` go up by 1000 every time?) It doesn't look as if the formula depends on previous iterations at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I realized that such a reduction of code on redundancy could be brought forward, hence the disclaimer above that the code I put can be made better but for my actual code I do require the kounter to kount for all iters. Thanks though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably looking for this `%`

```py
# when the remainder of t divided by 1000 equals zero
if t % 1000 == 0:
    print(kounter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rest of the division of your loop variable by the number of steps you want to run between samples for printing the value of the variable.

```
STEPS_PER_SAMPLE = 1000 # You can change this as you see fit
dt=10**(-3)
for i in range(1,100001):
    t=i*dt;
    kounter=e**(t*(dt**3))
    if i % STEPS_PER_SAMPLE == 0:
        print(kounter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a look-up "list" which contains multiple of 1000.

```
start, end, step = 1000, 11000, 10**3 # outside the for-loop
...
    if i in range(start, end, step)):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the equivalence between integer division and true division

```
if (t//1000)==(t/1000):
    print(konter)
```